# comparison between two dates vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, if-statement, datepicker

I have a problem with the comparison of my go dates with the return date. Since this morning I have tried several things but nothing works. I would like to display an error message if the person selects the same date as the return. But this doesn't work. Who can tell me what's wrong with my code? thanks in advance :)

```
<template>
    <div >
       <datepicker v-model="dateSelectAller"  lang="fr" type="date" format="dd-MM-YYYY" :lowerLimit="Date.now()" ></datepicker>                                     
   </div>
   <div v-show="!isSuccess">
     <span class="error-text" v-if="errors.timeAllerErrors">{{ errors.timeAllerErrors }}</span>
   </div>
   <div >
     <datepicker  v-model="dateAnterieurRetour"  lang="fr"  type="date" format="dd-MM-YYYY" :lowerLimit="Date.now()"></datepicker>
    </div>
    <div v-show="!isSuccess">
      <span class="error-text" v-if="errors.dateRetour">{{ errors.dateRetour }}</span>
    </div>                                        
</template>

<script>
    data(){
        return{
            format,
            dateSelectAller:new Date(),
            dateAnterieurRetour: new Date(),
            isSuccess:false,
            errors:{}
         }
      }
    beforeMount(){
       this.dateAnterieurRetour = this.dateAnterieurRetour.setDate(this.dateAnterieurRetour.getDate() +1)
   },
    watch:{
        
        dateSelectAller(newValue){
            if(newValue >= this.dateAnterieurRetour){
                this.errors['dateAller'] = 'Choisir une date inférieur à celle de retour'
            }else{
                this.errors['dateAller'] = ''
            }
            console.log(newValue)
            
            if(this.date1 === this.date2){
                return this.errors['timeRetourErrors'] = 'test erreur'
            }else{
                return this.errors['timeRetourErrors'] = ''
            }
        },
        
        dateAnterieurRetour(newValue){
             console.log(newValue)
            if(newValue <= this.dateSelectAller){
                
                this.errors['dateRetour'] = 'la date choisi n\' est pas valide!'
            }else{
                this.errors['dateRetour'] = ''
            }
            console.log(newValue)
        },
     },
    methods:{
        getFormat () {
            return this.format(new Date(this.dateSelectAller) , 'dd-MM-yyyy', {locale: window.locale})
        } ,
        
        getFormatRetour () {
            return this.format(new Date(this.dateAnterieurRetour) , 'dd-MM-yyyy', {locale: window.locale})
        } ,
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Did you tried timestamp comparison?

Comment: As @0x30c4 said, try to work with the timestamp and not the Date object instead. Its much easier to compare numbers than string/objects

Answer (score 0):

Where are you setting `isSuccess`? Right now it looks like the error divs will never appear since isSuccess isn't in your data or computed values

Comment: Thanks @Kellen for the response. actually I forgot to write isSuccess and errors in my datas when I created the post. I changed. What is suppressing is that it works when the outbound date is greater than the return date but it does not work when it is equal to the return date.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for trying to help me. I have just found a solution, that when the outgoing date and the same as the return date, the return date will advance by one day more. The problem came from the date format since when I retrieved my date it arrived in this format: 12251511511 and the outgoing date: 12/04/2021 that's why. I therefore change the format of the return date so that it can be compared to the outgoing date. :)